# Flash not running debugger any more. Possible socket issue in Windows-10?

Tags: sockets, actionscript-3, debugging, windows-10

### Bounty Update

*I am leaving the question essentially the same, but I just want to point out at the beginning here that I'm most interested in help trying to get the socket between flash (Adobe Animate) and the native debugger working again, as I believe that is the issue I'm having. Or is it a socket between flash and Windows?*

---

### Original Question

I've apparently turned something off?  Even when I write really bad code (like trying to call a function that isn't there or divide an integer into a fraction), the flash player boots, shows a background color and stops there.  No messages in the output window or compiler errors window.  If I fix my code, it all runs fine, but for about 30 minutes (ever since I started trying to work with bitmaps for a sprite sheet) I get no runtime errors no matter what kind of mistake I type in my code.  Anyone know how to turn it back on?

I've checked my actionscript settings and I have both warning mode and strict mode checked on.

Could it be a socket issue?  I admit I have little to no experience working with sockets and only a surface understanding of what that even means.  I've added the socket tag.  If someone can see that this is clearly nothing to do with sockets, by all means, I'll remove the tag.

**UPDATE: 6/22/16**

- I just reinstalled Adobe Animate CC 2015.2 and no change. I'll try compiling it in flash builder when I get a chance to help pigeon hole the problem. (Edit 6/24: flash builder worked! But my trial version expired the next day so is no longer a viable option).
- And I just tried something in the command prompt in Windows 10 as an administrator:

  ```
  netsh winsock reset catalog
  netsh int ip reset reset.log hit
  ```

which I found another user on flashdevelop.org used to fix a similar issue, but no change.

- And I just tried debugging in Flash Builder.  It worked fine (debugger caught bugs) but my trial version expired the next day.

**update 6/24**

- I've tried launching debugger for AIR from within the Adobe Animate CC IDE and it works fine if there are no bugs; it fails to do anything visible (no Iphone emulator, no swf window) if I put a typo or error in the code.
- I also just deleted winsock and winsock2, rebooted Windows, then reinstalled winsock and winsock2. No change.

**update 6/25**

- Just tried a system restore in Windows to set all my files and settings and drivers etc. to the way it was a week and a half ago... Also completely uninstalled all Adobe products and reinstalled. No change. I can only imagine that wiping my hard drive and reinstalling Windows would do the trick, but come on, it hasn't come to that has it?

As VC.One suggested, I checked the compile error window (cannot believe I didn't check before! Maybe when I checked before there were no compile errors... Only runtime errors?) and the errors are showing up there. Does this mean that it's catching compile errors but just not runtime errors?

Comment: be sure to use debug flash player

Comment: You mean the option under menu>debug>Debug Movie? As in ctrl+shift+enter on the PC?  I've tried that and it works if I have no errors. But if I have an error in my code, literally nothing happens. No debugger is initialized and no flash player is launched. If I have no errors in my code, the player launches and the debugger runs. Or are you talking about something else? Thanks.

Comment: I mean that error console works only in debug player, but looks like you have one. May be some local socket connection issues, flash uses socket to communication with debug info

Comment: You shouldnt have to re-install Windows. Check with Adobe forum too (staff are members). I cant re-produce your problem but just for testing... Regarding it "doesn't work, if I put a typo/error in the code"... In the IDE's AS3 settings if you **deselect** "Strict Mode" & "Warnings Mode" does it try to show an SWF output window? Also even if it fails with typo/error does the Compiler Errors show anything (use ALT+F2 to bring it up)?

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for looking into it.  Actually, now that you mention it, the compile errors window DOES show the errors.  Could I possibly have not checked that before?  This truly does fix my problem, I think, because all I'm missing now is just the pop-up window I used to get.  So, still a strange behavior that I have no explanation for, but it is hardly a chore to check the compile errors window.  With either or both "Strict" and/or "warning" mode deselected the SWF output window shows (with my correct background color and size) the same thing happens (reports compile errors in window)

Comment: @VC.One but maybe this only reports compile errors (as the window title suggests)? So this won't help me entirely. I'll try coding in some runtime errors tonight and see if that window helps at all then.

Comment: When you force/test a runtime error... make sure you have Compiler Errors (**ALT+F2**) and also Output (**F2**). By Output I mean the window that shows traces (and runtime issues). One of those should have some feedback for you.

Comment: Yep, I see that they do. This is sufficient for the time being. I'll let the bounty go a few more days and maybe someone will have some further insight on how to get it back to "normal", but if you want to make this an answer, I'll bump you the bounty if nothing better comes along. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it's showing something. I've added a possible solution using workspaces. That might be as close to "normal" as you can get. Also you didn't change any screen resolution or involve a 2nd display? I'm wondering if something went off-screen and stayed there?

Comment: @VC.One no 2nd display. No screen resolution changed.  I'll try your new suggestion in a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you force/test a runtime error... make sure you check

- **Compiler Errors** (**ALT+F2**) and also **Output** (**F2**). 
   By **Output** I mean the window that shows traces (and runtime issues). One of those two should have some feedback for you.

A possible solution is to save a new **Workspace**. So with those windows for **Compiler Errors** and **Output** both open (or tabbed, I tab them next to my **Timeline**) go to **Window** (in top options like File/Edit/Debug etc) and choose **Workspace**, then into that you choose **New Workspace**. Give it a name in the pop-up and okay everything.

Flash should always load that current workspace (next time, go to **Workspace** option again, check that your specified workspace [by name] has a **tick** next to it...).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I actually already have my workstation set up exactly like this.  The only thing I'm not getting like I used to, now, is the error pop-up window.  So it's not TOO much of a chore to just click on the tab for that window... it's just all a little weird, now.  I'll toss you the bounty if nothing more revalatory comes through because I really appreciate your time on this, and you did help me realize that the error messages were still coming through, which makes it usable again.  cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible pitfalls:
1 - Use the debug player
2 - Make sure there isn't somewhere a try/catch enclosing the portion of code that triggers the event that may lead to an error
3 - Socket issue: may be exported in debug mode but swf cannot connect to debugger (it waits in a blank state for 60 seconds I guess)
4 - Does it compile ok? If there are compilation errors you may get an SWF anyway but then it will not start
...

Comment: Thanks. 1. Check 2. Check 3. Likely possibility 4. Well, I want to say yes to this, but I don't want to assume that I understand what you mean, so I'll clarify what does happen. If there are no errors in my code, it runs as it is supposed to (I think this means it is compiling, right). If I insert an error into the code of any kind and in any place, the swf loads with a blank background (of the color that I set in the document properties panel) and zilch else happens.

Comment: There's 2 kind of errors: compile time, and runtime. Compile time errors are reported while you create the SWF, therefore SWF is created, but actionscript is not converted to bytecode, therefore you only have an empty SWF (if your first frame is white and empty, you will only see white). Runtime errors occur at run time. That means, there are no errors in code that block compilation, but, while the app is running, errors will occur. This kind of errors are visible in the debug player, and if you tick "allow debugging" you will also know the line in code. These can be handled in try/catch.